# Simple Mixed Model with 1 Fixed and 1 Random Effect

Tags: r, anova, statistical-significance, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I have various datasets I need to analyse regarding soil properties, all in the same fashion, with one fixed effect (which is a position along a transect, indicating different land uses). Now my main level of replication is across different transects, which will obviously have some form of random variance associated with them, and so I want to account for this in my statistical analyses.

So, in `lme4` I specified a mixed model to this specification

```
model <- lmer(variable.of.interest ~ transect.position + (1|transect))
```

Now, when I analyse the above model against a model without the transect position term, I get exactly the results I was expecting, and then plugging the above model into `anova()`, I get the F values, d.f. etc. that I need.

However, I can't figure out how to say, for my overall report, that the random effect of transect does not make any difference to the overall analyses (i.e. I can't get a p-value, F value, d.f. etc.).

Help?

Comment: Hi Ewan, welcome. Could you be a bit more precise about your question? What exactly do you want to test/show?

Comment: Ok, so, Im looking at different soil properties within agricultural fields, with soil samples taken from a seciton of woodland and at various points into the field. On each of these samples, I have performed a variety of analyses, e.g. organic carbon, nitrogen, water holding etc etc. So for example, I want to show that organic carbon declines from the woodland and into the field, which is the "transect.position" term. And all I want to do with the mixed model is acount for the random effect of the potentially different soil properties along each transect.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. But you already managed to calculate the mixed effect model to account for the random effects. Is your question "How can I show that the random effects model is an improvement over the normal model with no random effect"?

Comment: Sorry, no. I want to be able to quote for a statistical output that the random effect of "transect" has no significant effect on the overall model output.

Comment: What do you mean by "no significant effect on the overall model output."?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I mean no significant effect on the "variable.of.interest". such as organic carbon, nitrogen etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [likelihood ratio test (LRT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) to test whether a random effect is significant. First, fit the random effects model. Then fit the model without the random effect. Extract and store the log-likelihood for each model using `logLik` and calculate the twice difference between the log-likelhood of the mixed effects model and the normal model. Use a $\chi^{2}_{1}$ distribution to calculate the $p$-value. Let me give an example:

```
library(lme4)

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy, REML=FALSE) # ranodm effects model (random intercept for each Subject)

fm2 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, data=sleepstudy) # model without a random effect

D <- 2*as.numeric(logLik(fm1) - logLik(fm2))  # likelihood ratio statistic
D
[1] 106.2144                                # the chi2-value is very large

2*pchisq(D, 1, lower.tail=FALSE)            # p-value
[1] 1.323472e-24
```

In this case, the random effect of "Subject" clearly has an influence and should be included.

Alternatively, use the `nlme` package and the function `lme` to run the mixed-effect models. Then you can the `anova` function directly to calculate the likelihood ratio test:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

fm1 <- lme(Reaction ~ Days, random=~1|Subject, data=sleepstudy, method="ML")

fm2 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, data=sleepstudy)

anova(fm1, fm2)
    Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
fm1     1  4 1802.079 1814.851 -897.0393                        
fm2     2  3 1906.293 1915.872 -950.1465 1 vs 2 106.2144  <.0001
```

Which provides the same result as the one we've manually calculated.